# How to migrate Windows IIS to Azure

Tags: windows, azure, iis, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage

I gave up on P2V -  that stuff (Disk2VM)  is a big waste of time.

I want to move all of our IIS Websites from local on-premise server to Azure.

Now I have started with using Azure PaaS and Iaas in early 2014,  I'm mostly comfortable with classic VM ( IaaS)  however,  I'm not sure If I should use the new portal with new VM's or some PaaS or other?

1. IIS  - 20 -30 websites
2. Task Scheduler  - 20-40 tasks
3. Services
4. batch files ...

Thoughts how to do mass migration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All Azure service are moving to new Azure portal at the moment. I would suggest you create resources at Azure new portal if you want to avoid the risk. For this scenario. The best solution is to move on-premise server to Azure VM directly. So that we need not to redeploy project, recreate task scheduler and services.

Comment: So I should create new VM in new portal and then how do I get all my IIS websites etc. into the VM without doing them 1 at a time?

Comment: If you create a new VM in Azure. You need to install the IIS and move the files to the new VM. If you move your on-premise server to Azure directly. All the environment and files will be existed on the VM.

Comment: I created a VM and have IIS running on it.    I already wasted 3 days with the P2V ,  Disk2VHD is a joke.   GPT and boot sector issues  , it was no fun and waste of time..   So I would like to get these IIS apps all copied.  How exactly can I do it without the P2V ?